# Is there a visual studio code extension to auto space and auto format example section in scenario outline?

Tags: visual-studio-code, bdd, autoformatting

I want to have an **extension from visual studio code** which **auto format** content under **Examples section** as below.

This is for **behave framework**.
Below code depicts scenario outline.

```
   Given I put <thing> in a blender,
    when I switch the blender on
    then it should transform into <other thing>

 Examples: Amphibians
   | thing         | other thing |
   | Red Tree Frog | mush        |
```

I have a long list of arguments and it is very tedious to work with that.

Note: I currently use these extensions

1. Cucumber (Gherkin) Full Support
2. Python

**What I tried:**
I tried numerous code formatter extensions none of which support this requirement.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you can't find a formatter to do it write it yourself, or write an extension with a command to format the selected text according to your specs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Format document** option by the Visual studio code does what is intended.

1. Select the feature file
2. Right click on the editor
3. Click on **Format document**

Comment: becuase the Cucumber extension has a format document/selection function

Answer (score 0):

I have written a first version of a table formatter for Behave files

Extension [Behave](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-behave)